# Number Partition Algorithm Generator in Delphi XE8

Tags: delphi, math, numbers, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

How to make efficient and simplest algorithm to output a list of number `N` [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) in **Delphi XE8**?

For example `N=4`, the result (Lets say listed in a `TListBox`):

```
4
3 + 1
2 + 2
2 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

I have tried something, decided to use a dynamic array:

```
var
  IntegerArray: array of Integer;
```

To count the ones, twos, threes,...

And this to type out the dynamic array in a `TListBox`:

```
procedure TMForm.AddItem;
var
  Temp: String;
  I: Integer;
  II: Integer;

begin

  Temp:= '';
  for II:= 0 to Length(IntegerArray)-1 do
  begin

    for I := 0 to (IntegerArray[(Length(IntegerArray)-II)-1]-1) do
    begin
      Temp:= Temp+IntToStr(Length(IntegerArray)-II-1);
      Temp:= Temp+'+';
    end;
  end;

  delete(Temp,length(Temp),1);
  ListBox1.Items.Add(Temp);
end;
```

And started writing the algorithm (so far works but uses only numbers 1,2 and 3 to write partitions), but it seems I need to rewrite it to use recursion (so it will use all available numbers to write partitions), and that's my question; how to use recursion here?

```
function TMForm.Calculate(MyInt: Integer): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;

begin
  ListBox1.Clear;
  GlobalInt:= MyInt;
  Result:= 0;

  SetLength(IntegerArray, 0);
  SetLength(IntegerArray, (MyInt+1));
  IntegerArray[1]:= MyInt;
  AddItem;
  Result:= Result+1;
  //
  if MyInt>1 then
  begin

    repeat  
      IntegerArray[1]:= IntegerArray[1]-2;
      IntegerArray[2]:= IntegerArray[2]+1;
      AddItem;
      Result:= Result+1;

    until ((IntegerArray[1]/2) < 1 );

    if MyInt>2 then
    repeat
      IntegerArray[3]:= IntegerArray[3]+1;
      IntegerArray[1]:= MyInt-IntegerArray[3]*3;
      IntegerArray[2]:= 0;
      AddItem;
      Result:= Result+1;

      if NOT ((IntegerArray[1]/2) < 1) then
      repeat
        IntegerArray[1]:= IntegerArray[1]-2;
        IntegerArray[2]:= IntegerArray[2]+1;
        AddItem;
        Result:= Result+1;
      until ((IntegerArray[1]/2) <=1 );

      IntegerArray[1]:= MyInt-IntegerArray[3]*3;
      IntegerArray[2]:= 0;
    until ((IntegerArray[1]/3) < 1 );

    //if MyInt>3 then...


  end;

  Edit1.Text:= IntToStr(Result);
end;
```

---

Example of running the current program:

[image]

### Update

Managed to make it work like this:

```
procedure TMForm.Calculate(MyInt: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;

begin
  ListBox1.Clear;
  GlobalInt:= MyInt;
  ItemCount:= 0;

  SetLength(IntegerArray, 0);
  SetLength(IntegerArray, (MyInt+1));
  IntegerArray[1]:= MyInt;
  AddItem;
  ItemCount:= ItemCount+1;
  //
  if MyInt>1 then
  Step2;

  if MyInt>2 then
  for I := 3 to MyInt do
  Steps(I);

  Edit1.Text:= IntToStr(ItemCount);
end;

procedure TMForm.Steps(n: Integer);
var
  I,II: Integer;

begin
  if not ((IntegerArray[1]/n) < 1 ) then
  repeat
    IntegerArray[n]:= IntegerArray[n]+1;
    //
    IntegerArray[1]:= GlobalInt;
    for I:= 3 to GlobalInt do IntegerArray[1]:= IntegerArray[1]-IntegerArray[I]*I;
    //
    AddItem;
    ItemCount:= ItemCount+1;
    Step2;

    if n>3 then
    for II := 3 to (n-1) do
    begin
      Steps(II);
    end;

  until ((IntegerArray[1]/n) < 1 );
  //
  IntegerArray[n]:= 0;
  IntegerArray[1]:= GlobalInt;
  for I:= 3 to GlobalInt do IntegerArray[1]:= IntegerArray[1]-IntegerArray[I]*I;
end;

procedure TMForm.SpinBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SpinBox2.Value:= SpinBox1.Value;
end;

procedure TMForm.Step2;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
    if NOT ((IntegerArray[1]/2) < 1) then
    repeat
      IntegerArray[1]:= IntegerArray[1]-2;
      IntegerArray[2]:= IntegerArray[2]+1;
      AddItem;
      ItemCount:= ItemCount+1;

    until ((IntegerArray[1]/2) < 1 );

  IntegerArray[2]:= 0;
  IntegerArray[1]:= GlobalInt;
  for I:= 3 to GlobalInt do IntegerArray[1]:= IntegerArray[1]-IntegerArray[I]*I;
end;

procedure TMForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //
end;
```

But clearly, I need some optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, the simplest implementation is recursive.

There are some possibilities for optimization (for larger values it would be nice to store partitions of smaller values and use them again and again), but I think that for big N values the result list size will be too huge for output

```
//N is number for partitions, M is maximum part value 
//(used here to avoid permutation repeats like 3 1 and 1 3)
procedure Partitions(N, M: integer; s: string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if N = 0 then
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s)
  else
    for i := Min(M, N) downto 1 do
      Partitions(N - i, i, s + IntToStr(i) + ' ');
end;

begin
  Partitions(7, 7, '');
```

gives output

```
7 
6 1 
5 2 
5 1 1 
4 3 
4 2 1 
4 1 1 1 
3 3 1 
3 2 2 
3 2 1 1 
3 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 1 
2 2 1 1 1 
2 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I noticed that the result list is indeed too huge later on, how could I then by the simplest way compute just the number of the partitions instead of the whole list?

Comment: To calculate the number of partitions, you can use dynamic programming. One approach is memoization - make a table (2D array), fill it's entries during recursion or use ready value from the table if exists

Comment: @Matta adding directly to TMemo is SLOOOOW you can use some temp string variable `txt` instead and when whole partition is done copy it to `Memo1.Text=txt` or `Memo1.Lines.Add(txt)`. This is also slow due to huge amount of reallocation of string used by recursion and heap/stack trashing. Instead you can use some form of list of list of integer ... preallocate it to some reasonable size (tighted to `N`) and that should speed things up considerably. Or preallocate your strings with spaces and insert to them incrementally without reallocations

Comment: @MBo **Nice piece of code (+1) I ported it to VCL/C++ with string output I mentioned above like this:** AnsiString Partitions(int n,int m=0,AnsiString s="") { if (!m) m=n; if (!n) { if (s=="") return ""; s[s.Length()]='\r'; return s+"\n"; } int i; AnsiString txt=""; i=m; if (i>n) i=n; for (;i;i--) txt+=Partitions(n-i,i,s+AnsiString(i)+'+'); return txt; }

Comment: @Matta if you want just the number of partitions then just remove the string parameters from recursion and instead add to some integer variable (can be outside recursion tail to speed things up). Then will this be much much more faster due to much much lover heap/stack trashing even if you do not change the algo

Comment: @Spektre There is no need to generate partitions (in any representations) to just calculate their number. More effective methods exist.

Answer (score 1):

From your link there was a reference to: [Fast Algorithms for Generating Integer Partitions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.1287&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
.

Implementing the proposed fastest algorithms there (ZS1 and ZS2) looks like this:
(Note, there is no recursion here!)

```
procedure PartitionsZS1(n: Integer);
var
  x: TArray<Integer>;
  i,r,h,t,m: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(x,n+1);
  for i := 1 to n do x[i] := 1;
  x[1] := n;
  m := 1;
  h := 1;
  WriteLn(x[1]);
  while (x[1] <> 1) do begin
    if (x[h] = 2) then begin
      m := m + 1;
      x[h] := 1;
      h := h - 1;
    end
    else begin
      r := x[h] - 1;
      t := m - h + 1;
      x[h] := r;
      while (t >= r) do begin
        h := h + 1;
        x[h] := r;
        t := t - r;
      end;
      if (t = 0) then
        m := h
      else begin
        m := h + 1;
        if (t > 1) then begin
          h := h + 1;
          x[h] := t;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    for i := 1 to m do Write(x[i]);
    WriteLn;
  end;
end;

procedure PartitionsZS2(n: Integer);
var
  x: TArray<Integer>;
  i,j,r,h,m: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(x,n+1);
  for i := 1 to n do x[i] := 1;
  for i := 1 to n do Write(x[i]);
  WriteLn;
  x[0] := -1;
  x[1] := 2;
  h := 1;
  m := n - 1;
  for i := 1 to m do Write(x[i]);
  WriteLn;
  while (x[1] <> n) do begin
    if (m-h > 1) then begin
       h := h + 1;
       x[h] := 2;
       m := m - 1;
    end
    else begin
      j := m - 2;
      while (x[j] = x[m - 1]) do begin
        x[j] := 1;
        j := j - 1;
      end;
      h := j + 1;
      x[h] := x[m - 1] + 1;
      r := x[m] + x[m - 1]*(m-h-1);
      x[m] := 1;
      if (m - h) > 1 then
        x[m-1] := 1;
      m := h + r - 1;
    end;
    for i := 1 to m do Write(x[i]);
    WriteLn;
  end;
end;
```

---

```
program Project61;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
  PartitionsZS1(7);
  WriteLn;
  PartitionsZS2(7);
end.
```

Outputs:

```
7
61
52
511
43
421
4111
331
322
3211
31111
2221
22111
211111
1111111

1111111
211111
22111
2221
31111
3211
322
331
4111
421
43
511
52
61
7
```

Comment: Some partitions are missed (52 421 etc)

Comment: @MBo, so it seems. I will see if I misinterpreted somewhere. Can't do it right now, though.

Comment: @MBo, Ok problem fixed. There were a missing bracket in the publication.

Comment: @Matta, Like MBo said, if you put the data into a 2D integer matrix instead of using strings, it will gain speed.